# how to change json file import path in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, path

Hi here is what is working and what i need to change.
I have under my SCR folder a data folder for testing purposes in which there are many json files.

I actually have many react list component which I want to change to only one generic component by passing the json filename and path instead of hardcoding it.
this works

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as s from '../../components/Shared/ListCards.styles'

import ListData from '../../data/user.json'

const ListCards = () => {
    const listJSX = ListData.map((user, index) => {
        return ()
```

I would like to change

```
import ListData from '../../data/user.json'
to
import ListData from 'path/filename.json'
```

path and filename is stored in localStorage

```
localStorage.getItem('colName')
```

Comment: So you're looking to change it to a known absolute path and filename, or are these unknown?

Comment: for the moment the path is decided by a drop down menu.
and is hard coded

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic imports

```js
const { default: ListData } = await import('path/filename.json');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports

---

You may want to considering using the fetch api instead, if the path stored inside your local storage relates to a URL:

```js
const ListCards = () => {
    const { listData, setListData } = useState([]);
    (async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/urlpath/filename.json')
        const data = await response.json()
        setListData(data)
    })();
    const listJSX = listData.map((user, index) => {
        return ()
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it and was not able to make it work.
the problem is always putting the path variable.

like fetch('/urlpath/filename.json')
how would insert the urlpath and filname.
Backticks fetch(`${urlpath}${filename}`)
that<s where i am stock

Comment: my path is not a url, it points to a json file in a relative folder '../../data/files.json.

```const ListCards = () => {
 const { default: ListData } = await import('../../data/user.json')```

I the following error when saving.
```Unexpected reserved word 'await'```